# Let X be a cont or discrete RV. Define a function $f:R\rightarrow R, f(t)=E(X-t)^2$. Show that f attains its minimum at t=EX

Tags: probability

Let X be a continuous or discrete RV. Define a function $f:R->R,$ 
$$f(t)=E(X-t)^2$$
Show that f attains its minimum at t=EX

I have no idea how to do this problem, because I don't know how to interpret it. I'm assuming $E(X-t)^2$ is the expectation with respect to X-t and then I don't really know what it means by "attains its minimum". I'm assuming that means it's lowest value? But I don't really know how that applies to discrete or continuous variables.

Comment: It applies to any r.v. Hint: Use linearity of expectation. Can you find extrema of such function of variable $t$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X-t)^{2}=EX^{2}-2tEX+t^{2}$. This quadratic function of $t$ attains its minimum when $-2EX+2t=0$ or $t=EX$.